# I'm using a form to push objects to an array but they aren't displaying properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a library app where users input data into a `form` and the values they enter are displayed in its own `div`.

I have this `array`

```
let myLibrary = [
  {
    title: "The Once and Future King",
    author: "White",
    pages: 654,
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
  },
];
```

which is automatically displaying each `object` (for testing purposes) on my page thanks to this `forEach()`

```
myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
  const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");
  const addBook = document.createElement("div");
  addBook.className = "book";
  bookContent.appendChild(addBook);
  addBook.innerHTML = `
    <div class="title">
    <p class="bookTitle">
    <span>${book.title}</span>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
    <p>
    Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
    </p>
    <p>
    Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
    </p>
    </div>`;
});
```

The `forEach` makes it so every `object` inside my `array` is displayed in its own 280x365 pixel `div` and the book title, author and page count is displayed in it's own `p` element. I'm also using `flex` for organization.

I also have a `form` which users can input a new book title, author and page number to add to their growing book collection.

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", updateLibrary);

function updateLibrary(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  const pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;

  const book = {
    title: title,
    author: author,
    pages: parseInt(pages),
  };
  myLibrary.push(book);
  console.log(myLibrary);
}
```

When I fill the form out, everything appears to work perfectly. I have `console.log` in my `updateLibrary` function and I notice the `object` is being pushed into the `array` like I want it to. But every time I hit the `submit` button, a new `div` isn't being created for the new book. I'm guessing this has to do with my `forEach` not triggering the new `object` but I can't find a way to fix this.

How can I better write my code so a new `div` is also being created with the new `object` every time I submit the `form`?

*What I've tried*

I've tried rearranging my code so the `forEach` is below the `array`, so the `updateLibrary` function is above and below the `forEach`.

I've also tried putting the `forEach` inside the `updateLibrary` function. That did make it work but it gave me an even worse bug.

Answer (score 1):

That is normal. The DOM (so the HTML within the page) is not automatically updated everytime that you change your array. If you want to work like this, I suggest you to look at ReactJS.

But to solve your problem, you must do 3 easy things here : create a function that will handle the display of your object in HTML, update your forEach to only call this new function, then, when a user create a new object, apply it this function :

```
const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");

function displayBook(book) {
    const addBook = document.createElement("div");
    addBook.className = "book";

    bookContent.appendChild(addBook);

    addBook.innerHTML = `
        <div class="title">
            <p class="bookTitle">
                <span>${book.title}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>
                Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
            </p>
        </div>`;
}

// Display your original object list
myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
  displayBook(book) 
});

// Handle your object creation
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", updateLibrary);

function updateLibrary(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    const author = document.getElementById("author").value;
    const pages = document.getElementById("pages").value;

    const book = {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        pages: parseInt(pages),
    };

    myLibrary.push(book);

    // Then, ask to display your book
    displayBook(book)

    console.log(myLibrary);
}
```

It should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects to update the DOM the moment you add a new book to the `myLibrary` array. For this, we will convert the `myLibrary` array into a new proxy object named `libraryProxy` and configure it.

```js
const myLibrary = [{
    title: "The Once and Future King",
    author: "White",
    pages: 654,
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
  },
];


const libraryProxy = new Proxy(myLibrary, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return target[prop];
  },
  // When you add a new element to the array, 
  // the set method will run and here we will update the DOM   
  // while adding the new element as newVal to the array.
  set(target, prop, newVal) {
    if (Number(prop)) {
      const book = newVal;
      // add new book to array
      target[prop] = book;
      // update the dom
      addBookToUI(book);
    };

    return true;
  }
})


const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

libraryProxy.forEach((book) => {
  addBookToUI(book);
})


function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const [title, author, pages] = document.querySelectorAll('form > input');

  // New book will be added to the array and the DOM will be updated
  libraryProxy.push({
    title: title.value,
    author: author.value,
    pages: parseInt(pages.value, 10)
  });
}

function addBookToUI(book) {
  const bookEl = document.createElement('div');
  bookEl.className = 'book';
  bookContent.appendChild(bookEl);

  bookEl.innerHTML += `
      <div class="title">
        <p class="bookTitle">
          <span>${book.title}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <p>
        Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
        Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    `;
}
```

```css
.book {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="title" />
  <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="author" />
  <input type="text" id="pages" placeholder="pages" />

  <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will go over it so I can better understand as I've never heard of Proxy before. One question I have

`pages: parseInt(pages.value, 10)`

What is the point of the 10? I've seen it before but could never fully grasp it.

Comment: It is radix(the base in mathematical numeral systems). Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for details and examples about parseInt and radix.